# I am unable to pusblish rostopics using MAVLINK with gazebo and px4..getting errors

Tags: ros, px4

I am newbie to PX4 , I have installed gazebo , and Cloned the Firmware.

I am trying to publish ros topics. But I am getting the Errors .

Steps I followed :

Terminal1 :

```
roslaunch mavros px4.launch fcu_url:="udp://:14540@127.0.0.1:14557"
```

Terminal2 :

```
source Tools/setup_gazebo.bash $(pwd)$(pwd)/build_posix_sitl_default

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:$(pwd)/Tools/sitl_gazebo

roslaunch px4 posix_sitl.launch
```

Errors which I am getting,

Terminal1 :

```
[ WARN] [1493507102.919495629]: TM: Clock skew detected (-0.019824184 s). Hard syncing clocks.
[ERROR] [1493507113.704105243]: FCU: Accel #0 fail: TOUT!
[ERROR] [1493507113.706679234]: FCU: Gyro #0 fail: TOUT!
[ WARN] [1493507113.944251371]: TM: Clock skew detected(0.012025608       s). Hard syncing clocks.
[ERROR] [1493507121.030549466]: FCU: Accel #0 fail: TOUT!
[ERROR] [1493507121.036021491]: FCU: Gyro #0 fail: TOUT!
[ERROR] [1493507121.630152661]: FCU: Accel #0 fail: TOUT!
[ERROR] [1493507121.634544822]: FCU: Gyro #0 fail: TOUT!
[ERROR] [1493507122.108005687]: FCU: Accel #0 fail: TOUT!
[ERROR] [1493507122.111951530]: FCU: Gyro #0 fail: TOUT!
[ERROR] [1493507122.829282656]: FCU: Accel #0 fail: TOUT!
[ERROR] [1493507122.830428095]: FCU: Gyro #0 fail: TOUT!
[ WARN] [1493507141.422615369]: TM: Clock skew detected (-0.016021096 s). Hard syncing clocks.
```

Terminal2 :

```
WARN [mavlink] [timesync] Hard setting offset.
WARN [mavlink] [timesync] Hard setting offset.
ERROR [sensors] Accel #0 fail: TOUT!
ERROR [sensors] Gyro #0 fail: TOUT!
WARN [mavlink] [timesync] Hard setting offset.
WARN [mavlink] [timesync] Hard setting offset.
WARN [mavlink] [timesync] Hard setting offset.
WARN [mavlink] [timesync] Hard setting offset.
WARN [mavlink] [timesync] Hard setting offset.
```

Please kindly help me with this issue.

Thank you!!